# Broken results on batch convert with ImageMagick command line on Linux

Tags: php, linux, shell, imagemagick, batch-processing

This is my IM command:

```
/usr/bin/convert 
'src.tif'
  -limit memory 0
  -limit map 0
  -limit file 0
  -alpha transparent
  -clip
  -alpha opaque
  -resize 800x600
  'end.png'
2>&1
```

So this will remove the white background of my TIFF by clipping the path that is given in the file. It will be resized and saved as transparent PNG.

I got no errors from IM running this.

But if I run this command with PHP to execute it on about 13000 files - I sometimes get these errors:

```
sh: line 1: 25065 Killed                  /usr/bin/convert \
            'public_html/source_files/XXXX123/XXXX123/XXXX123.tif' \
             -limit memory 0 -limit map 0 -limit file 0 -alpha transparent \
             -clip -alpha opaque -resize 800x600 \
            'public_html/converted/XXXX123/XXXX123/XXXX123_web.png' 2>&1

sh: line 1: 25702 Killed                  /usr/bin/convert \
            'public_html/source_files/XXXX123/XXXX123/XXXX123.tif' \
             -limit memory 0 -limit map 0 -limit file 0 -alpha transparent \
             -clip -alpha opaque -resize 800x600 \
            'public_html/converted/XXXX123/XXXX123/XXXX123_web.png' 2>&1
```

But the bigger problem is: Some of the pictures are broken. Below is a "bad" image on the left, a "good" image on the right (ondrag/on a dark background you see the problem better):

[image]
[image]

On running the command manually the result was ok. Only on running this PHP loop script will provide broken results. ( [PHP loop script](https://gist.github.com/CodeBrauer/6200c5ca6a5befe0208e) )

I run the script this way: `php55 run.php`. A simple loop with `find` as shell script provides same results.

So I searched, asked in the IM discourse server and run this procedure on 2 machines with different distribution (Debian Wheezy, Ubuntu Server 14.04)

**Note/EDIT 1:** Running the command in the terminal with the same file provides a perfect result.

**EDIT 2:** Added example TIFF file [here](http://gab3.de/share/new/)

Comment: Have you tried limiting/unlimiting the time, with `-limit time X` where `X` is in seconds. How about posting a working and a broken input image?

Comment: How much free space on your disk do you *really* have? How much RAM is available on your system? How many *inodes* are taken and how many are still available on your file system? Your `-limit [memory|map|file] 0` settings basically tell ImageMagick: *"Ignore all limits. You've enough resources!"*

Comment: @MarkSetchell, Links to broken / good images are in the post as well under the second code block.

Comment: The links are PNG files, not TIFs.

Comment: Sorry, some example files are here: http://gab3.de/share/new/

Comment: Another question: Is your problem reproducible? Does it return the b0rken result every time you run the command inside the PHP loop? (I mean: if running in the loop, does the b0rken result occur every time for the same image?) And every time when manually run the command for the b0rken image in a shell/terminal it will return a "good" result? Or is the problem appearing intermittently, affecting image A in one run, and image B in another run?

Comment: Did you try unlimiting the time yet?

Comment: The time isn't limited afaik. - The broken pictures are randomly different. Sometimes the first 150 are good and then nearly every third picture is broken. Sometimes the 22nd picture is already broken.

Comment: Your IM version is rather outdated, being v6.7.7. -- I wonder if you are experiencing a bug with the specific version you have installed. Do you have the opportunity to test your batch process with the same files on a different system with a more recent IM version?

Comment: I've here a VPS with Ubuntu 14.04 - and the latest stable I get for this system is 6.7.7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is an answer. For now it is pure speculation. So here goes...

By setting the limits to a `0` value, you are basically telling ImageMagick: *"Your resources are not limited at all. You do not need to care for any limits."*

- ***What if didn't set any limit?*** Remove all `-limit ... 0` parts from your command. In this case ImageMagick would use its built-in defaults, or the otherise defined settings (which may be contained in the *policy.xml* file of your IM installation, or through various *environment variables*). You can query the current limits of your system with the following command:

  ```
  identify -list resource
  ```

  On my system, I get these values:

  ```
  File       Area     Memory     Map       Disk  Thread  Throttle        Time
  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
   192    4.295GB       2GiB    4GiB  unlimited       1         0   unlimited
  ```
- ***What if you did set these limits to a reasonable value, that matches your system's really available resources?*** Assuming you have: 8 GByte of RAM, 50 GByte of free disk space and plenty of free *inodes* on your disk volume. Then try to set it like this: `-limit disk 10GB -limit memory 3GB -limit map 6GB`.

---

### ImageMagick resource management

For all its processing and intermediate steps, ImageMagick needs access to an intermediate *pixel cache memory/storage*, before it can deliver the final result.

This need for pixel cache storage can be satisfied by different resources:

- heap memory,
- anonymous memory map,
- disk-based memory map,
- direct disk.

ImageMagick makes use of all these resources progressively:

- Once heap memory is exhausted, it stores pixels in an anonymous map.
- Once the anonymous memory map is exhausted, it creates the pixel cache on disk and attempts to memory-map it.
- Once memory-map memory is exhausted, it simply uses standard disk I/O.

Disk storage is cheap but very slow too: it is in the order of 3 magnitudes (a thousand times) slower than memory. Some speed improvements (up to 5 times) can be obtained by using memory mapping to the disk-based cache.

ImageMagick is aware of various ways to control the amount of these resources:

1. ***Built-in default values***. These limits are: 768 files, 3GB of image area, 1.5GiB memory, 3GiB memory map, and 18.45EB of disk space.
2. ***`policy.xml` config file***. Please look up what's in your own *policy.xml* file. Use `convert -list policy` to find the location of this file first. Then use `cat /some/path/policy.xml` to see its contents. (The file uses an XML syntax. Don't forget: anything enclosed in `<!--`  and `-->` is a comment!) It also contains comments explaining various details. The *policy.xml* can define much more things than just the available limit resources. Settings in *policy.xml* take precedence over the built-in default values if they are defined there.
3. ***Environment variables***. Here is a list of environment variables which can limit IM resources: `MAGICK_AREA_LIMIT` (image area limits), `MAGICK_DISK_LIMIT` (disk space limit), `MAGICK_FILE_LIMIT` (maximum no. of open files limit), `MAGICK_MEMORY_LIMIT` (heap memory limit), `MAGICK_MAP_LIMIT` (memory map limit), `MAGICK_THREAD_LIMIT` (maximum no. of threads limit) and `MAGICK_TIME_LIMIT` (maximum elapsed time in seconds). These environment variables, if set, take precedence over the *policy.xml* config file.
4. ***`-limit <name> <value>` settings on command line***. The following `<names>` are recognized:

   - `width` (maximum width of an image). When limit is exceeded, exception is thrown and processing stops.
   - `height` (maximum height of an image). When limit is exceeded, exception is thrown and processing stops.
   - `area` (maximum number of bytes for any single image to reside in pixel cache memory).  When limit is exceeded, automagical caching to disk (possibly memory-mapped) sets in.
   - `memory` (maximum memory allocated for the pixel cache from anonymous mapped memory or heap).
   - `map` (maximum amount for memory map allocated for pixel cache).
   - `disk` (maximum amount of disk space permitted for use by pixel cache). When limit is exceeded, pixel cache is *not* created and a fatal exception is thrown.
   - `files` (maximum number of open pixel cache files). When limit is exceeded, all subsequent pixels cached to disk are closed and reopened on demand.
   - `thread` (maximum number of threads which can in parallel).
   - `time` (maximum time in seconds a process is permitted to execute). When this limit is exeeded, an exception is thrown and processing stops.

   The `-limit` setting on a command line takes precendence and overrides all other settings.

Comment: I've added the 'limit 0' just for testing. Changes nothing. Will try with limits.

Comment: The machine is running a Intel Xeon with 4c/8t @ 3.3GHz, 32GB RAM, 3TB HDD space (2,2TB free space). The command returns this https://gist.github.com/CodeBrauer/496e56397053c89d61b7

Comment: So what limit do you prefer for the machine mentioned one answer before?

Comment: @GabrielW: Which exact version is your ImageMagick? Please provide (links to) the output of the following commands: `convert -version` and `convert -list configure`.

Comment: So i tried it now `-limit disk 50GB -limit memory 10GB -limit map 20GB` and it works (for now) like a charm - my script is now about 15% done and all images I watched are looking good.