# Limit space and memory used by Imagemagick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, imagemagick, rmagick

I'm used Imagemagick on a rails application (with rmagick) but my server (Ubuntu) it's not very big and when i launch my convert process Imagemagick take all place/memory of my server (30GB HDD).

I would like limit the memory and the tmp file size, how can i do it ?

Answer (score 3):

Try running the command

```
identify -list resource
```

to see the resources you can control/limit. It gives this:

```
Resource limits:
  Width: 214.7MP
  Height: 214.7MP
  Area: 4.295GP
  Memory: 2GiB       <--- Default is 2 GiB
  Map: 4GiB
  Disk: unlimited
  File: 1920
  Thread: 1
  Throttle: 0
  Time: unlimited
```

Then you can control the memory using commands like this for both `convert` and `identify` and `mogrify`

```
identify -limit memory 1GiB -list resource
Resource limits:
  Width: 214.7MP
  Height: 214.7MP
  Area: 4.295GP
  Memory: 1GiB         <--- 1 GiB for duration of this command
  Map: 4GiB
  Disk: unlimited
  File: 1920
  Thread: 1
  Throttle: 0
  Time: unlimited
```

So, as you can see above, I limited memory to 1GB for the one command.

Equally, you can limit memory for `convert` with

```
convert -limit memory 1GiB -size ... file.png
```

You can also set the memory limit in an environment variable, single-shot, like this:

```
MAGICK_MEMORY_LIMIT=30000 identify -list resource
Resource limits:
  Width: 214.7MP
  Height: 214.7MP
  Area: 4.295GP
  Memory: 29.3KiB
  Map: 4GiB
  Disk: unlimited
  File: 1920
  Thread: 1
  Throttle: 0
  Time: unlimited
```

or like this for the rest of the session:

```
export MAGICK_MEMORY_LIMIT=500000
identify -list resource

Resource limits:
  Width: 214.7MP
  Height: 214.7MP
  Area: 4.295GP
  Memory: 488KiB
  Map: 4GiB
  Disk: unlimited
  File: 1920
  Thread: 1
  Throttle: 0
  Time: unlimited
```

Kurt also offers some great advice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27919679/2836621).

Comment: Ok then if I understand : I add "-limit memory 1GiB" to my convert command to limiting the memory use but for my tmp file size do you have a solution ?

Comment: That is `disk`, i.e. `-limit disk`

Answer (score 0):

```
$ man ulimit
```

Read about the *-f* entry and do:

```
$ ulimit -f 1024000
$ convert blah blah blah
$ ulimit -f <usual-value>
```

should limit the *convert* process to writing a 1G file.  Be sure to restore the original value afterward.